# Problem with packages when emacs is run as a daemon

Tags: package, start-up, emacs-daemon

I have a very odd problem when Emacs daemon is started by the system. Currently, I work on:

```
Emacs 28.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.36, cairo version 1.17.6) of 2023-01-03
```

After login in, I have to manually execute: `emacs --daemon` in the terminal. Then, Eamcs and packages work correctly. Starting daemon every time I log in is a little annoying, so I tried to automate it. I tried two methods:

- startup script (`Session and Startup` on Manjaro) where I put `emacs --daemon` or
- enabling a `emacs.service` run via systemd for a specific user.

For reasons I can't explain, packages do not work when the daemon is run by system. Two examples are AUCTeX and LSP. The first cannot see my custom LaTeX modules and does not even run `latexmk`. The latter is supposed to ask about project settings, which does not happen.

I checked `*Messages*` in all cases: running a standalone instance, starting a daemon from terminal, and finally when a daemon is started by the system, in all cases all init files get executed as expected.

When the daemon is running, I open a new frame with `emacsclient -c -a emacs`.

I wonder what may cause this issue and how I could debug it.

Comment: Do `M-x getenv PATH` in both terminal and script scenarios.  If the results are different this will go some way to answering yr question.

Comment: @FranBurstall I tried to look for differences between scenarios and did not recognise any differences. I also opened the shells and run `printenv` to compare environmental variables. The [Peder Klingenberg'a answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77695/18879) works, though. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had similar issues in the past, and they have always been due to differences in the environment between my interactive shell and the startup scripts.

I solved this by ensuring Emacs is always started from a shell that has been initialized as interactive.  So instead of running `emacs --daemon` from the startup sequence, I run `zsh -ic 'emacs --daemon'`.  (or `bash -ic 'emacs --daemon'` on machines where I run bash as the shell.)

Comment: Changing `emacs --daemon` to `bash -ic 'emacs --daemon'` solved my problem. Thanks for explanation